# Require either of two arguments using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Given:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar')

print(parser.parse_args('--foo 1'.split()))
```

How do I

- make at least one of "foo, bar" mandatory: `--foo x`, `--bar y` and `--foo x --bar y` are fine
- make at most one of "foo, bar" mandatory: `--foo x` or `--bar y` are fine, `--foo x --bar y` is not

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to code argparse combinational options in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603364/how-to-code-argparse-combinational-options-in-python)

Answer (score 442, accepted):

I think you are searching for something like [mutual exclusion](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) (at least for the second part of your question).

This way, only `--foo` or `--bar` will be accepted, not both.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('--foo',action=.....)
group.add_argument('--bar',action=.....)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

BTW, just found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603364/how-to-code-argparse-combinational-options-in-python) referring to the same kind of issue.

Comment: @jlengrand your answer still worked for me after I realized it actually solves both conditions proposed in the question (`XOR`, basically). My initial concern was that yours only solved only one of the two conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had an idea it was solving everything indeed, but wasn't sure any more :D. I'll edit the answer accordingly!

Comment: This doesn't answer the first bullet point of the question, requiring one but allowing both

Answer (score 49):

If you need some check that is not provided by the module you can always do it manually:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ...
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.foo is None and args.bar is None:
   parser.error("at least one of --foo and --bar required")
```

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue11588#msg226469) proposing to improve argparse to include different types of usage tested groups

Comment: alas! if only that open issue had gone anywhere...