# python: argparse with optional command-line arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to implement arguments parsing.

```
./app.py -E [optional arg] -T [optional arg]
```

The script requires at least one of parameters: `-E` or `-T`

What should I pass in `parser.add_argument` to have such functionality?

**UPDATE**
For some reason(s) the suggested solution with `add_mutually_exclusive_group` didn't work, when I added `nargs='?'` and `const=` attributes:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-F', '--foo', nargs='?', const='/tmp')
group.add_argument('-B', '--bar', nargs='?', const='/tmp')
parser.parse_args([])
```

Running as `script.py -F` still throws error:

```
PROG: error: one of the arguments -F/--foo -B/--bar is required
```

However, the following *workaround* helped me:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('-F', '--foo', nargs='?', const='/tmp')
parser.add_argument('-B', '--bar', nargs='?', const='/tmp')
args = parser.parse_args()

if (not args.foo and not args.bar) or (args.foo and args.bar):
   print('Must specify one of -F/-B options.')
   sys.exit(1)

if args.foo:
   foo_func(arg.foo)
elif args.bar:
   bar_func(args.bar)
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Require either of two arguments using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154946/require-either-of-two-arguments-using-argparse)

Answer (score 4):

You can make them both optional and check in your code if they are set.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.foo is None and args.bar is None:
   parser.error("please specify at least one of --foo or --bar")
```

---

If you want only one of the two arguments to be present, see [`add_mutually_exclusive_group`] (https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) with `required=True`

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
>>> group.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
>>> group.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
>>> parser.parse_args([])
usage: PROG [-h] (--foo | --bar)
PROG: error: one of the arguments --foo --bar is required
```

Comment: OP stated "At least one", which sounds like mutually exclusive is not what he wants.

Comment: @MaxNow, yes you are correct. Updated the answer to include at least one.

Comment: @ShashankV, thanks for your answer. Does `argparse` support checking optional parameters following the argument? For example, `script.py --foo FOO_BAR`  and FOO_BAR is optional.

Comment: `nargs="?'` makes the argument optional.  It's best used with both `default` and `const` parameters.  See the docs.