# How to allow required arguments to be omitted when a specific flag is used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

My code is as follows.

```
__version__ = 'v10'

class MyHelpFormatter(argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter):
       def _get_help_string(self, action):
              return action.help

def main():
       parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
              formatter_class=MyHelpFormatter,
              description=__version__
       )

       parser.print_usage = parser.print_help

       parser.add_argument("file", help="path to file/directory")

       parser.add_argument(
              "-t",
              "--type",
              type=str,
              default=False,
              help="file type",
       )

       parser.add_argument(
              "-c",
              "--config",
              action="store_true",
              help="change custom text",
       )

       parser.add_argument(
              "-v",
              "--version",
              action='version',
              version=__version__,
              help="thumb-gen version",
       )
```

In my code, it always requires the 'file' argument. It's ok.

Now I want call a function when it call with '--config' argument. But when I run `main.py --config` it also require the 'file' argument.

How to use the '-config' argument without entering the required argument?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Require either of two arguments using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154946/require-either-of-two-arguments-using-argparse)

Comment: Your code never calls `parser.parse_args()` or `main()`, and there's a lot of stuff that seems unrelated to the problem. Please provide a [mre]. I wrote one [here in a gist](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/065e9034095bfbcf169bc3b49fcd0c99) if you want to use it.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer The 'file' argument requires a flag when I use that solution. I do not need a flag for the 'file' in my code. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Often the cleanest solution is to make `--file` optional with a good default.  That way you don't care whether the user supplied the value or not.

Comment: Something like this: `group.add_argument('--file', nargs='?')` or default value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this.  First, you could make the file argument optional. After parsing is finished, your code checks if the `--config` flag was present ― if it wasn’t, then check if the file argument was given. If not, exit with an appropriate error message.

Alternatively you can use *two* parsers. The first one looks for `--config` and sets a flag (e.g. `do_config = True`); it does not require a file argument. Then use a second parser that only requires a file argument if `do_config` is False.